# Print all logs in console when running Selenium test with Capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, logging, cucumber, capybara

I am using Capybara with Selenium driver for my acceptance tests

**Versions used:**
`Selenium` 2.53.1
`Capybara` 2.7.1
`cucumber` 2.2.0
`cucumber-core` 1.3.1

According to [Selenium/Logging](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Logging), known log types are `browser`, `client`, `driver`, `performance` and `server`. I would like to log all these log types in console output in realtime.

Based on what I understood, **to enable full logging** I am configuring Capybara as following:

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  config.app_host = ENV['APP_HOST'] # APP HOST from Cucumber.yml file
  config.default_driver = :selenium
  config.match = :prefer_exact
  config.default_max_wait_time = 10

  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
      app, 
      :browser => ENV['BROWSER'].downcase.to_sym,
      :desired_capabilities => {
        :loggingPrefs => {
          :browser => "ALL",
          :client => "ALL",
          :driver => "ALL",
          :server => "ALL"
        }
      }
      )
  end
end
```

Where `ENV['BROWSER']` is 'Chrome'.

What I am still unclear is how to print the logs to console. I am looking for a way to print the logs for all scenarios.
I tried adding following code to `hooks.rb`

```
After do |scenario|
  puts @browser.driver.manage.get_log(:browser)
  puts @browser.driver.manage.get_log(:client)
  puts @browser.driver.manage.get_log(:server)
  puts @browser.driver.manage.get_log(:driver)  
end
```

but `@browser` is nil.

Also tried following in `hooks.rb`

```
After do |scenario|
  puts page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)
end
```

But works only for browser logs.

**Question:** How do I print these logs after each scenario, or even better in realtime?